# Highchart with L shaped Area/PlotBands

Tags: highcharts

[image: High Charts]

Is it possible to achieve such area/plotbands(as shown in image) in highchart?

Comment: image is added as link with 'High Charts' Title

Comment: PlotBands are rendered along the whole Axis. In your case use [`polygon`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.polygon) series.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pawel Fus, it really helped.